# capture hidden NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, image, nswindow

I'm able to capture `NSWindow`s which are visible using code simular to the [SonOfGrab Example](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html)

But how can I capture a hidden `NSWindow`? Or what is the way to hide a `NSWindow` from the user but to still appear in de Windowserver?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible to capture the contents of an NSWindow which isn't visible on-screen. When a window is minimized/hidden/whatever, the visual representation is dropped to save memory.

(Not sure on exactly how this is managed, feel free to chime in if you have a deeper knowledge of the window system. I only know this from experience, trying to capture windows with CamTwist and BoinxTV.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by:

```
NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[window windowImageShot] size:window.frame.size];
```

category to NSWindow:

```
- (CGImageRef)windowImageShot
{
    CGWindowID windowID = (CGWindowID)[self windowNumber];
    CGWindowImageOption imageOptions = kCGWindowImageBoundsIgnoreFraming | kCGWindowImageNominalResolution;
    CGWindowListOption singleWindowListOptions = kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow;
    CGRect imageBounds = CGRectNull;

    CGImageRef windowImage = CGWindowListCreateImage(imageBounds, singleWindowListOptions, windowID, imageOptions);

    return windowImage;
}
```

Comment: +1, this is wicked. kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow lets you take a screenshot of a windowID even if it isn't in front. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This won't work if you minimize the application.  CGWindowListCreateImage will give you nill.