# How to obtain firemonkey MacOS window ID?

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

On MS Windows one can obtain a window handle by using:

```
WindowHandleToPlatform(winhandle).wnd
```

How does one obtain a MacOS Window "id":

for example a function that accepts a window id:

```
CGWindowListCreateImage(
  CGRect screenBounds, 
  CGWindowListOption listOption, 
  CGWindowID windowID,  // <------------------ here
  CGWindowImageOption imageOption);
```

Comment: It does not _require_ window ID, literally. The [reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454852-cgwindowlistcreateimage) says, _"The ID of the window to use as a reference point when determining which other windows to include in the image. For options that do not require a reference window, this parameter can be kCGNullWindowID."_ Do you want to create a composite image from a window list starting at certain window ID within that list?

Comment: and if anyone knows if `WindowHandleToPlatform(h).Wnd.windowNumber` is correct let me know, and it could be added as an answer, but I'm not sure at all if this is right.

Comment: @Victoria, possibly, but what if you did want a reference window? How would you obtain the windowID of it, or whatever is required?

Comment: This answer suggests that it does correspond to windowNumber: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20374294/3164070

Comment: Assuming objective C's [self windowNumber] is the Delphi equivalent.. I would test this out to verify, but I cannot get delphi to work with the server program that runs it remotely due to internal compile error.  Updating XCode SDK to see if it solves the issue

Comment: @Programmz: yes, `WindowHandleToPlatform(h).Wnd.windowNumber` is correct

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, `WindowHandleToPlatform()` retrieves a `TWinWindowHandle` for a given `TFmxHandle`.  `TWinWindowHandle` contains (amongst other things) the window's `HWND`.

On OSX, `WindowHandleToPlatform()` retrieves a `TMacWindowHandle`, which contains the window's `NSWindow`, `NSView`, `NSTrackingArea`, and `NSOpenGLView` objects.  You can get a `CGWindowID` from the `NSWindow.windowNumber` field, eg:

```
WindowHandleToPlatform(winhandle).Wnd.windowNumber
```

Comment: I would accept this answer, but I cannot test it yet to verify - when I do get macOS working (hopefully), I'll revisit this page to accept answer